# How to state the Axioms of Category Theory in Predicate Logic?

Tags: category-theory

I have been trying to formally state the axioms of category in predicate logic. It seems that I will need one-place predicates for objects and arrows, two-place predicates for heads and tails of arrows and a three-place predicate for composition. I am trying to avoid the use of the functional notation found in most definitions of CT, notation which IIUC more properly belongs in the domain of set theory.

---

**EDIT:** Predicate logic alone would seem to be completely unworkable as a language to express the axioms of category theory. I don't see any way around starting with 11 universally quantified variables in predicate logic for the axiom of associativity, compared to only 3 when using the '$\circ$' notation for the composition of arrows. (Sigh)

Comment: Can you give an example of the functional notation to which you refer?

Comment: Functions or $k$-ary operations can be replaced by $k+1$-ary predicates, with suitable axioms of unique existence to express functional dependence of the "output" argument on the inputs.

Comment: Note that extending first-order logic to allow partial functions is in some sense a "trivial" extension - you're just adding symbols to stand for first-order expressions. So you can use a partial function symbol for composition, and still retain all the niceness of first-order model theory (e.g. compactness, Lowenheim-Skolem, etc.) as long as you're careful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can actually make do with a smaller language: one ternary relation (composition $Comp$), and two unary functions (source $s$ and target $t$). We conflate objects with identity arrows, so we don't need a separate sort for objects at all.

The axioms now are straightforward:

- "Compositions behave correctly." For every pair of arrows $\alpha,\beta$, there is at most one arrow $\gamma$ such that $Comp(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$; and such a $\gamma$ exists iff $s(\beta)=t(\alpha)$.
- "The source and target of an identity arrow are itself." $t(t(\alpha))=s(t(\alpha))\wedge t(s(\alpha))=s(s(\alpha))$.
- "Compositions are associative." This is a bit long. For instance, to write $(\alpha\beta)\delta=\alpha(\beta\delta)$, we'd write $Comp(\alpha, \beta,\gamma)\wedge Comp(\gamma, \delta, \epsilon)\wedge Comp(\beta, \delta,\theta)\implies Comp(\alpha, \theta, \epsilon).$ But it's totally doable.
- "Identities are identities." $Comp(\alpha, \beta,\gamma)\wedge s(\alpha)=\alpha\implies \beta=\gamma$, and similarly for composition on the right.
- "Identities are their own source and target." $t(\alpha)=\alpha\iff s(\alpha)=\alpha$.

And that's it!

---

This is not due to me; I read about it in Goldblatt's book *Topoi*. I forget who he attributed it to.

Comment: Do we need a unary predicate for "identity arrows"?

Comment: @hardmath No, an identity arrow is one satisfying $\alpha=s(\alpha)$ (or $\alpha=t(\alpha)$).

Comment: A variant on this definition (which even avoids including $s$ and $t$ in the language) is used in Freyd's book _Abelian Categories_, published in 1964.  That might be the first place it was written down (it is for a surprising number of ideas in category theory!).

Comment: *Very* helpful.  Who ever knew that category theory was so simple!