# Is the theory of the category of topological spaces computable?

Tags: general-topology, logic, category-theory, computability

*This question is inspired by [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324547/which-branches-of-mathematics-can-be-done-just-in-terms-of-morphisms-and-composi).*

Ignoring size issues, there is a [natural way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593198/28111) to view a category as a first-order structure in a finite language. In light of this we can ask about the computational complexity of the *first-order theory* of a given category. Note that a lot of important structure is lost when passing to the first-order level; nevertheless, it still seems interesting to me.

Plenty of categories are easily checked to have very complicated first-order theories - for example, assuming the axiom of choice in the background we can identify the finite sets as those for which every self-injection is a surjection, and since Cartesian products and disjoint unions give the usual arithmetic we have that the first-order theory of the category **Sets** is not computable.

*Incidentally, choice isn't needed here, but the non-choice argument is a bit more tedious.*

My question is:

> Is the first-order theory of the category **Top** of topological spaces (with morphisms being continuous maps) computable?

My suspicion is that the answer is no. An obvious way to prove this would be to show that the *finite discrete spaces* are first-order characterizable here, since then we could run the same argument as for **Sets**; however, I don't see how to do this. *(In particular, the notion of "compact objcet" of a category is not obviously first-order expressible, so [that characterization of finite discrete spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288648/what-are-compact-objects-in-the-category-of-topological-spaces) doesn't seem to help.)*

---

There are weaker versions of this question which could be asked:

- We could focus on the theory of the *categorial equivalence class* of **Top** - that is, the set of sentences true in every category which is categorially equivalent to **Top**. In general categorial equivalence does not imply elementary equivalence (since [a two-element category can be categorially equivalent to a one-element category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories#Examples)), so this is a nontrivial weakening.
- We could also restrict attention to a subcollection of categories - that is, pin down some non-first-order categorial property $P$ of **Top**, and then ask for a first-order theory which distinguishes the theory of **Top** (or the theory of the categorial equivalence class of **Top**) *within this class*. For example, [Lawvere's ETCS characterizes **Sets** up to categorial equivalence amongst the locally small complete categories](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/01/an_elementary_theory_of_the_ca.html).

I am also interested in comments along these lines; however, my main question is specifically about the first-order theory of **Top**.

EDIT: [David Roberts brought to my attention](https://mathoverflow.net/a/324550/8133) Schlomiuk's paper [An elementary theory of the category of topological spaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1970-149-01/S0002-9947-1970-0258914-7/home.html); among other things, this gives a computable (indeed, finite) theory characterizing **Top** up to categorial equivalence amongst complete categories, as well as in a more subtle sense (any such category is equivalent to **Top**$^\mathfrak{S}$ for some model $\mathfrak{S}$ of ETCS).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me assume choice. It is possible to distinguish discrete spaces from other spaces: those are precisely the spaces $X$ such that for any epimorphism $f:Y\to X$ admits a section $g:X\to Y$ (i.e. $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_Y$). To see this, recall first that epimorphisms in **Top** are just the surjective continuous maps.

If $X$ is discrete, then for any epimorphism $Y\to X$ there is a set-theoretical section by AC, which is automatically continuous.

Conversely, suppose every epimorphism into $X$ splits. Let $Y$ have the same underlying space as $X$, but discrete topology. Then the identity on points is a continuous map from $Y\to X$, and since it's an epimorphism, it admits a section, which shows that $X$ is discrete too.

The subcategory of discrete topological spaces is equivalent to the category of sets, and you already know it's uncomputable. It follows the first-order theory of **Top** is undecidable.

It's not clear to me if this proof can be modified so as to avoid the use of AC.

Edit: a proof without the use of AC: we will again distinguish the subcategory of discrete spaces. Let $1$ be a one-point space (a terminal object) and $2$ a two-point discrete space (a space with exactly two maps from $1$ to it, and with $4$ maps from it to itself) and $i:1\to 2$ any map. Then $X$ is discrete iff for any map $f:1\to X$ there is a map $g:X\to 2$ such that $g\circ f=i$, and for any $f':1\to X,f'\neq f$, we have $g\circ f'\neq i$.

This expresses that for any point $x\in X$, there is a map $X\to 2$ which takes $x$ to one point, and all other points to a different one. Since $2$ was discrete, this implies $\{x\}$ is open, so $X$ is discrete.

Since you say you know **Set** has uncomputable theory even without AC, we deduce the same for **Top**.

Comment: Neat, I didn't think of that! I'll hold off on accepting for a bit to see if a choice-free answer can be whipped up.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Added a different, AC-free proof :)

Comment: Beautiful - accepted.

Comment: Per your last line, see Eric's answer, which is what I had in mind for **Sets**.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method of defining natural numbers in $\mathbf{Set}$ (without Choice) which generalizes immediately to $\mathbf{Top}$.  Namely, we can just express the second-order Peano axioms directly in our categorical language.  Let us fix a terminal object $1$.  Then we can define the natural numbers as a triple $(N,s,0)$ where $N$ is an object, $0:1\to N$ is a morphism, and $s:N\to N$ is a morphism such that they satisfy the second-order Peano axioms, namely:

- $s$ is injective (i.e., monic).
- $0$ is not in the image of $s$ (that is, $0$ cannot be factored as a composition $s\circ f$ for any $f:1\to N$).
- No proper subobject of $N$ contains $0$ and is closed under $s$.  That is, if $i:A\to N$ is any monic morphism such that $0$ factors through $i$ and $s\circ i$ factors through $i$, then $i$ is an isomorphism.

For $\mathbf{Set}$, these properties pick out the usual structure of natural numbers (up to isomorphism), and for $\mathbf{Top}$, they pick out the natural numbers with the discrete topology (proof: given any space $N$ with element $0$ and map $s:N\to N$ satisfying the first two conditions, the subset generated by $0$ under $s$ can be given the discrete topology to get a space $A$ and a continuous injection $i:A\to N$, and then the third condition implies $i$ is an isomorphism).

(As an aside, while these axioms work in $\mathbf{Set}$ or $\mathbf{Top}$, there are other axioms for natural numbers besides the Peano axioms which are more natural from a categorical perspective, such as the notion of a [natural numbers object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number_object).)

We can then fix any such $(N,s,0)$ and define a natural number as a morphism $1\to N$.  We can define morphisms $+:N\times N\to N$ and $\cdot:N\times N\to N$ as the unique morphisms satisfying the usual recursive definitions, and these give binary operations on our natural numbers, so we can interpret arithmetic in our category.

Comment: This was the argument I had in mind for the choice-free version w/r/t **Sets** - stupid though it seems, I didn't notice that it worked for **Top** as well!